# How can I access the value from an Object inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, rss

When i loop from a rss data I want to extract the url value from an object.

```
$.ajax({
 url      : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=30&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.dnoticias.pt/rss/actualidade/geral'),
 dataType : 'json',
 success  : function (data) {
   if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
   $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {

     title = e.title;
     description = e.description;
     category = e.categories[0];
     media = e.mediaGroups;
     console.log(media);
   }
  }
});
```

Here is the output from the console log:

```
mediaGroups: Array[1]
 0: Object
  contents: Array[1]
   0: Object
    type: "image/jpeg"
    url: "http://...."
```

Thanks

Comment: could you try to get console.log(media.mediaGroups.contents.url);

Comment: could you try to get console.log(media.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url);

Comment: Says:  TypeError: media is undefined

Comment: @nunof, see my answer. You object has two properties with the name: `mediaGroups`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you've shown `mediaGroups` is an array of objects, which themselves contain a `contents` property which is another array of objects, so you need to use nested loops to pull out each `url` property from those objects.

```
$.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(_, entry) {
    $.each(entry.mediaGroups, function(_, mediaGroup) {
        $.each(mediaGroup.contents, function(_, content) {
            var url = content.url;
            // use url as required here...
        });
    });
});
```

If you always only ever want to retrieve the first item from the array, and can guarantee that each child array will contain at least one item, then you can simply access them by index like this:

```
$.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, entry) {
    var url = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url;
    // use url as required here...
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9y21jaj0/)

Comment: It could be because you have several mis-matched brackets and braces in your code. I added a working example to my answer for you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You just access array elements by indexing, and property by property names:

```
 e.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].type
```

Answer (score 0):

if the arrays have only one element, then it's as simple as this:

```
media = e.mediaGroups[0];
contents = media.contents[0];
```

then you can do somehting like this:

```
someVar1 = contents.type;
someVar2 = contents.url;
```

otherwise you will have to iterate through `mediaGroups` and through `contents` as well

Comment: seems like the errors were caused by the "several mis-matched brackets and braces in your code" as Rory mentioned, nevertheless i'm glad you got the help you needed.